# Python Numpy operation on vectorelements that share value

Tags: python, numpy

Eddited: (I've done myself a disservice by trying to simplify the problem and i did so unsuccesfully)

I have a vector which represents months. Lets say its 120 long and contains 10 1's representing january 10 2's representing february and so on for all the months. I also have a vector representing data for these months and they are paired such that vector element 20 in the month vector corresponds to vector element 20 in the data vector. Now i need to sum all of the datavalues which correspond to the same month and make a new vector consisting of these aggregated values for the month. How do i do this so that it sums the vectorelements that share value (example all those that have 1 for january) rather than doing a for loop for i in range(1,13).

The reason i would like to avoid loops is that i need to do this for both months days and hours, and ive got datapoints for a whole year recorded every minute and doing it with loops for hours for a whole year would yield a for loop with i in range(22000) approximately.

Sorry for being so confusing in my question i apologize but would still appreciate help.

Comment: What do you mean with 'elements that share a value' could you give a specific example with, say, 10 elements?

Comment: Editted the question. Sry for the confusion :). I appreciate the time.

Comment: ok, so you have two arrays, one of the form 'months = [1,2,3,4,...,1,2,3,]` and one of the form `data = [[...],[...],[...]]` and now you want sums of all januaries, all febuaries and so forth, makin a total of 12 values -- do I get this right?

Comment: Yes you got it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not quite sure, if I understood correctly, but let's edit the answer as things become more clear:

I did not find a way to avoid looping entirely, but in my example the months only get looped through once. The idea is to create a `set` with all the individual months and then create a dictionary that holds the sums of the according data values. If you need a `numpy` array in the end, these are easily converted back.

```
import numpy as np

size = 120
vec = np.array([i%12+1 for i in range(size)])
data = np.random.random(size)

uniques = set(vec)

sums = {}

for i in uniques:
    sums[i] = sum(data[vec==i])

print(vec)
print(uniques)
print(sums)
```

this gives:

```
[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1
  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2
  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3
  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4
  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12]
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}
{1: 4.9439443614487342, 2: 5.399789601378199, 3: 4.8294837878695169, 4: 4.8454779051312888, 5: 4.8247673795432426, 6: 6.793755999311454, 7: 6.4136044876257436, 8: 4.320805218279439, 9: 6.9444739443947814, 10: 4.49598659161187, 11: 3.8670833795862358, 12: 5.2844155391474272}
```

**Note** that the algorithm is designed to work also if the months are not ordered (as I had understood from the original version of the question), or if months are missing. Otherwise there would be simpler approaches using `numpy slicing`.

Comment: Thanks Thomas :D

I really appreciate it. I dont think i would have come to such asolution just trying to google python operators.

Comment: @SimonMabe You're welcome. In the future, if you add an explicit example of your input and your desired output, you are much more likely to get help quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not clear from your question why you want to avoid a for loop, but a list comprehension seems to do the trick:

```
import numpy as np
array_with_random_integers = np.ceil(np.random.rand(1,1042)*100)   #1042 is just random length
array_with_counts = [np.sum(array_with_random_integers==element) for element in np.arange(1,101)]
sum(array_with_counts)    #Returns 1042, showing that all elements are counted
```

I'm assuming that you mean "counts" when you write "sums" in

> sums all of the vectorelements that share value

Comment: Editted the question. Sry for the confusion :). I appreciate the time.